# Unused var in non-debug configuration

Tags: c, dry

I often write code like this:

```
int result = someMethod(arg1,arg2,...);
assert(result==0)
```

Let's say assert() is defined something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define assert(e) if(!e) printf("something's wrong");
#else
#define assert(...)
#endif
```

The first piece of code would give a warning about 'result' being an unused var.

I could do something like:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    int result = someMethod(arg1,arg2,...);
#else
    someMethod(arg1,arg2,...);
#endif
assert(result==0)
```

But that seems quite non-dry to me ...

What else could I do?

Comment: Why are you redefining `assert`?  Just `#include <assert.h>`.  Also, note that `NDEBUG` is typically used rather than `DEBUG`.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but C doesn't have methods.  SomeMethod() should be named someFunction().

Comment: @WilliamPursell You're right, that's silly :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
int result = someMethod(arg1,arg2,...);
assert(result==0);
(void)result;
```

Answer (score 1):

A macro like `assertion_code` to enable certain code pieces only in debug configuration.

```
#if defined(NDEBUG)
#define assertion_code(v)
#else
#define assertion_code(v) v
#endif
```

Now you can write

```
assertion_code(int result =) expr();
assert(result == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace and line breaks are irrelevant to the compiler, so...

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    int result =
#endif
    someMethod(arg1,arg2,...);
assert(result==0)
```

Comment: Your probably want to wrap that in a macro to make it usable.

Comment: @pmr Just showing the mechanics, but yup...better with a macro.

Answer (score 0):

There is the explicit way:

```
static inline void debug(const char *msg)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("%s\n", msg);
#else
    (void)msg;
#endif
}
```

Then:

```
if (someMethod(arg1,arg2,...) != 0) {
    debug(message);
}
```

As there is a fair chance you won't want to continue as normal when something is wrong, the explicit conditional clause is perhaps going to be useful anyway. Or were you planning to ignore errors when DEBUG is turned off?